# FrameTicks in DateListPlot doesn't support "All" in Mathematica 12

Tags: plotting, ticks

In mathematica 12,

```
DateListPlot[{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11}, {2000, 8}, FrameTicks -> All]
```

gives

[image]

And the error message is

> A ticks specification in the value of FrameTicks should be None,
>   Automatic, a function, or a list of ticks.

But "All" works in Mathematica 11. Is it a bug?

If only `Automatic` is supported, How can I add ticks on other sides of frame?

Comment: Seems like a bug that should be reported to WRI.  In the meantime, here's a workaround that gives you everything except the date labels across the top: `DateListPlot[{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11}, {2000, 8}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{All, All}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]`

Comment: @theorist Thank you. But date label is essential. We can not lose it

Comment: Happy to help.  But note that the workaround doesn't lose the date label; it just gives it on the bottom only.

Comment: @theorist Oh, my fault. I naively thought only two All will lose date label. It works as I wanted. Thank you very much!